# Selenium unexpectedly closing tab without typing driver.quit(), producing errors (Using Pycharm)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, pycharm

I'm currently using the latest version of Selenium, and there seems to be a problem with Selenium unexpectedly closing without me using the quit method. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
article_count = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#articalcount a")
article_count.click()
```

And it opens the browser before closing and giving me the following error:

```
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62C894A62+57106]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C80CF52]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C6DE2CB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C71786E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C71795C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C750477]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C7369FF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C74E522]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C736793]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C70CE81]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C70E064]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62CB44222+2873042]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62CB96590+3209792]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62CB8F3AF+3180639]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62C925F25+652245]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C818618]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C8147C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C8148BC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62C804C33]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF274026AD+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF2894AA68+40]
```

Can someone help me with this?
(Note that i was using Pycharm)

**EDIT:**
The Output full output in the terminal was this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lyuan\Desktop\100_days_of_code\day48\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    article_count = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#articalcount a")
  File "C:\Users\lyuan\Desktop\100_days_of_code\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 739, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\lyuan\Desktop\100_days_of_code\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\lyuan\Desktop\100_days_of_code\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#articalcount a"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.171); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BB4B4A62+57106]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB42CF52]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB2FE2CB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB33786E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB33795C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB370477]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB3569FF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB36E522]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB356793]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB32CE81]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB32E064]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BB764222+2873042]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BB7B6590+3209792]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BB7AF3AF+3180639]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BB545F25+652245]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB438618]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB4347C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB4348BC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7BB424C33]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFD436A26AD+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFD4484AA68+40]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: Can you include the command line output as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#articalcount a"}
```

...implies that no element was identified immediately within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) using the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used. Hence the browser got closed.

---

### Solution

To click on the *article count* ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='articlecount']//a"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#articlecount a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: wikipedia]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)